# Check which mesh element is inside the original polygons

Tags: c++, algorithm, matlab, cgal

I have a set of non-overlapping polygons. These polygons can share nodes, edges, but strictly no overlapping.

Now, I am going to mesh them using Constrainted Delaunay Triangulation (CDT) technique. I can get the mesh without problem.

My problem is, after the mesh, I want to know which mesh element belongs to which original polygon. MY current approach is to compute the centroid for each mesh element, and check which of the original polygon this centroid falls into. But I don't like this approach as it is very computationally intensive.

Is there any efficient ways to do this ( in terms of Big O the runtime)? My projects involve tens of thousands of polygons and I don't want the speed to slow down.

Edit: Make sure that all the vertices in a mesh element share a common face is not going to work, because there are cases where the all the vertices can have more than one common face, as below ( the dotted line forms a mesh element whose vertices have 2 common faces):

[image]

Comment: You'll not lose this information in the first place if you do your book keeping during the triangulation properly.  If you use a library, make sure it accepts the point set in terms of objects.  Then simply keep references to the original polygons in the point objects.

Comment: Hi Graviton, have you found an answer to that question, since you post it?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two options, both somehow mentioned :

1. Maintain the information in your points/vertices.  See this other [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418332/customizing-cgal-kernel-with-my-own-point-class).
2. Recompute the information the way you did, locating each mesh element centroid in the original polygon, but this can be optimized by using a [`spatial_sort`](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Spatial_sorting_ref/Function_spatial_sort.html), and locating them sequentially in your input polygon (using the previous result as hint for starting the next point location).

Answer (score 0):

What about labeling each of your original vertices with a polygon id (or several, I guess, since polys can share vertices). Then, if I understand DT correctly, you can look at the three verts in a given triangle in the mesh and see if they share a common label, if so, that mesh came from the labeled polygon.

Comment: this is not going to work as I can find a counter example where all the 3 vertices share 2 common polygon id ( instead of 1).

Comment: I believe you but I am having a hard time visualizing it

Comment: What if before you do the triangulation, you impose a convex constraint on your polygons? So your edge case where one wraps the other would be split up into several sub polygons.

Answer (score 0):

As Mikeb says label all your original vertices with a polygon id.

Since you want the one that's inside the polygon, just make sure you only go clockwise around the polygons, this makes sure that if the points overlap for two polygons you get the one facing the correct direction.

I would expect this approach to remain close to O(n) where n represents number of points as each triangle can at only have one or two polygons that overlap all three points.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new graph G(V,E) in the following way. For every mesh create a node in V. For every dashed edge create an edge in E that connects the two corresponding meshes. Don't map solid edges into edges in E.

Run ConnectedComponents(G).

Every mesh will be labeled with a label (with 1-to-1 correspondence to polygons.)

Comment: `Run ConnectedComponents(G).` Can you be more explicit on how this would solve the problem at hand?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can call CDT separately for each polygon, and label the triangles with their polygon after each call.