# Is it possible to use Eigen as types for CGAL?

Tags: eigen, cgal

CGAL uses its own data types for points. I would like to know if there is any way to use Eigen types instead of CGAL::Point_3.

Comment: In which algorithm do you want to use that? The difficulty is not the same for all.

Comment: I want to use it as the default point type. For example, I have some tetrahedra that right now have CGAL::Point_3 point. Would be nice to have tetrahedra made of Eigen::Vector3d. I found myself converting to eigen, doing an affine transformation and converting back to CGAL...

Comment: I don't think that's possible (without a very large effort). For the CGAL->Eigen conversion, you could use Eigen::Map so it doesn't even copy. Copying for Eigen->CGAL is not that bad.

Comment: Its not a matter of performance, at least for now. It was about simplicity for coding.

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418332/customizing-cgal-kernel-with-my-own-point-class

Comment: I pulled it over here https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/discussions/5395